# HTML/CSS/PHP Submenu coloring

Tags: php, html, css

Can't find what is wrong with my menu. I want that when you hover a sub menu item background color would be only for submenu not for menu items. I tried everything here is menu css.

I tried `#menu ul li a:hover` but still affect menu items and sub items..... And I need only subitems.

```
#menu
{
    list-style: none;
    padding-right: 8%;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 3.5%;
    clear: right;
    text-indent: 10px;
}

#menu ul
{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}

#menu ul a
{
    display: block;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 32px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

#menu ul li
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu ul li.current-menu-item
{


}

#menu ul li:hover
{






}

#menu ul ul
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 92%;
    left: -64%;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
}
#menu ul ul li
{
    float: none;
    width: 190px;
}
#menu ul ul a
{
    line-height: 120%;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

#menu ul ul ul
{
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}

#menu ul li:hover > ul
{
    display: block;
}
```

[image]

```
   <?php

            $args = array(
                'theme_location' => 'pre_primary'
            );

            ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( $args); ?>
```

Comment: Could we get your HTML code too or [DEMO](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Dont think that it will help but i updated

Comment: Is it online? link will be helpful of site

Comment: We need to see the CSS that creates the `:hover` effect...at the moment that is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use immediate child selector!

```css
#menu > ul > li > a:hover
```

Answer (score 0):

To style anchors in nested list use the following `css` selector:

```
#menu li ul li a:hover
```

It will affect only second level items.